# Fit image and Resize using library uCrop of Yalantis for android

Tags: android, image, libraries

I´m usig [uCrop library](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) in my project and it´s awesome!

I have two questions.

Is it possible to adjust or fit an image within the area? Something like the parameter ScaleType:centerInside of android, for example :

[image]

And the other question : in the library can we use the parameter withMaxResultSize . it is available, or how we might implement a withMinResultSize making a resized image ?

I'll make a mention to [Oleksii Shliama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4903519/oleksii-shliama) , but my question is for all users.

Thank you very much for your interest.

Regards!

Comment: I've answered here: https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/issues/138.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the answer here - https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/issues/138